# AngularJS, faceted search is very slowly

Tags: angularjs, filter

I use this faceted search https://plnkr.co/edit/wNbRidDCLmwIBWUOz5bz into my project but with 430 items, filter counter is very slow... I have input lag when I use searchbox.

In HTML :

```
({{ (filteredItems | filter:query | filter:count(group.name, facet)).length }})
```

In controller :

```
$scope.count = function (prop, value) {
    return function (el) {
        return el[prop] == value;
    };
};
```

Do you have an alternative?

Comment: a fast workaround to avoid input lag and avoid too much useless computation is debouncing model biding in your search input by adding `ng-model-options="{ debounce: 200 }"`

Comment: no changes. The problem is the count function.

Comment: Can you update the fiddle to include all of the items? Response is basically instantaneous in what you've posted.

Comment: 1.I would upgrade from Angular 1.01 to a more recent release. 2. I tried to wrap your code in an IIFE and add use strict and when I do so it fails. I'd work on cleaning these things up and then see if this is still an issue. There have been a lot of performance improvements to Angular since 1.01.

Comment: thanks! my angular version is 1.3.14. I Cannot reproduce with jsfiddle :(

Answer (score 0):

I forked your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ema7wpse/ and addressed the issues I mentioned above. I'm not seeing any performance issues with it, but your original fiddle performed ok for me, so your mileage may vary.

```
(function() {

  angular.module('myApp', []);

  var uniqueItems = function(data, key) {
    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var value = data[i][key];

      if (result.indexOf(value) == -1) {
        result.push(value);
      }

    }
    return result;
  };

   angular.module('myApp').controller("MyCtrl",MyCtrl)

  function MyCtrl($scope, filterFilter) {
    $scope.usePants = {};
    $scope.useShirts = {};
    $scope.useShoes = {};

    $scope.players = [{
      name: 'Bruce Wayne',
      shirt: 'XXL',
      pants: '42',
      shoes: '12'
    }, {
      name: 'Wayne Gretzky',
      shirt: 'XL',
      pants: '38',
      shoes: '10'
    }, {
      name: 'Michael Jordan',
      shirt: 'M',
      pants: '32',
      shoes: '9'
    }, {
      name: 'Rodman',
      shirt: 'XSXL',
      pants: '42',
      shoes: '11'
    }, {
      name: 'Jake Smitz',
      shirt: 'XXL',
      pants: '42',
      shoes: '12'
    }, {
      name: 'Will Will',
      shirt: 'XXLL',
      pants: '42',
      shoes: '12'
    }, {
      name: 'Youasdf Oukls',
      shirt: 'XL',
      pants: '38',
      shoes: '10'
    }, {
      name: 'Sam Sneed',
      shirt: 'XL',
      pants: '38',
      shoes: '10'
    }, {
      name: 'Bill Waxy',
      shirt: 'M',
      pants: '32',
      shoes: '9'
    }, {
      name: 'Javier Xavior',
      shirt: 'M',
      pants: '32',
      shoes: '9'
    }, {
      name: 'Bill Knight',
      shirt: 'M',
      pants: '32',
      shoes: '9'
    }, {
      name: 'One More',
      shirt: 'M',
      pants: '32',
      shoes: '9'
    }, {
      name: 'Player One',
      shirt: 'XXL',
      pants: '42',
      shoes: '11'
    }, {
      name: 'Space Cadet',
      shirt: 'XXL',
      pants: '42',
      shoes: '12'
    }, {
      name: 'Player Two',
      shirt: 'XXXXL',
      pants: '42',
      shoes: '12'
    } {
      name: 'Bill Knight',
      shirt: 'M',
      pants: '32',
      shoes: '9'
    }, {
      name: 'One More',
      shirt: 'M',
      pants: '32',
      shoes: '9'
    }, {
      name: 'Player One',
      shirt: 'XXL',
      pants: '42',
      shoes: '11'
    }, {
      name: 'Space Cadet',
      shirt: 'XXL',
      pants: '42',
      shoes: '12'
    }];

    // Watch the pants that are selected
    $scope.$watch(function() {
      return {
        players: $scope.players,
        usePants: $scope.usePants,
        useShirts: $scope.useShirts,
        useShoes: $scope.useShoes
      }
    }, function(value) {
      var selected;

      $scope.count = function(prop, value) {
        return function(el) {
          return el[prop] == value;
        };
      };

      $scope.pantsGroup = uniqueItems($scope.players, 'pants');
      var filterAfterPants = [];
      selected = false;
      for (var j in $scope.players) {
        var p = $scope.players[j];
        for (var i in $scope.usePants) {
          if ($scope.usePants[i]) {
            selected = true;
            if (i == p.pants) {
              filterAfterPants.push(p);
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if (!selected) {
        filterAfterPants = $scope.players;
      }

      $scope.shirtsGroup = uniqueItems($scope.players, 'shirt');
      var filterAfterShirts = [];
      selected = false;
      for (var j in filterAfterPants) {
        var p = filterAfterPants[j];
        for (var i in $scope.useShirts) {
          if ($scope.useShirts[i]) {
            selected = true;
            if (i == p.shirt) {
              filterAfterShirts.push(p);
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if (!selected) {
        filterAfterShirts = filterAfterPants;
      }

      $scope.shoesGroup = uniqueItems($scope.players, 'shoes');
      var filterAfterShoes = [];
      selected = false;
      for (var j in filterAfterShirts) {
        var p = filterAfterShirts[j];
        for (var i in $scope.useShoes) {
          if ($scope.useShoes[i]) {
            selected = true;
            if (i == p.shoes) {
              filterAfterShoes.push(p);
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if (!selected) {
        filterAfterShoes = filterAfterShirts;
      }

      $scope.filteredPlayers = filterAfterShoes;
    }, true);


    $scope.$watch('filtered', function(newValue) {
      if (angular.isArray(newValue)) {
        console.log(newValue.length);
      }
    }, true);
  }

  angular.module('myApp').filter('count', function() {
    return function(collection, key) {
      var out = "test";
      for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        //console.log(collection[i].pants);
        //var out = myApp.filter('filter')(collection[i].pants, "42", true);
      }
      return out;
    }
  });

  angular.module('myApp').filter('groupBy',
    function() {
      return function(collection, key) {
        if (collection === null) return;
        return uniqueItems(collection, key);
      };
    });

})();
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I don't reproduce either with jsfiddle :(

Comment: Ok, I can reproduce. My datas have many more properties. 8 exactly.

Comment: I added console.log(prop, value) to the count function and it's being called twice for every item whenever the search value is changed. I'm not entirely sure how to eliminate this, but obviously, that would help.

Comment: I also think but I don't know how

Comment: I added console.log(el.Id) and the function it's being called 3 times for every object but it's normal because there is 3 facets for each object

Comment: You're doing some pretty heavy lifting here and $scope.$watch is pretty expensive. I think your code looks pretty clean overall, but perhaps another approach might be warranted. I know one thing I'd want to do is delay any filtering until the user has finished typing. When that actually happens is pretty subjective, but perhaps deferring all action until the user clicks a search button might be the best course of action. There is an awful lot of looping going on here.

Comment: I'm beginner to angular, I don't know how to do.

Comment: Where can I put delay?

Comment: I'm not really sure where you'd put a delay. If it were me, I would eliminate all of the watches and call the search from the click of a button.